# C# WPF different size from IDE after debugging?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gOLN.png]

I am having a problem with different appearance in `Blend/VS2012 IDE` and in `Debugging`.
In `IDE`, the `Rectangle` is at the center, but when it is compiled or debugged, the size of the margin is different. In my view, this occurs because the size of the window border is different. I really want to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

Thank You.

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="202" Width="194">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="171" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186">
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="151" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166"/>
</Grid>
```

Edited `XAML` code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="202" Width="194">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="171" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186">
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="151" Margin="10" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="166"/>
</Grid>
```

Result is the same. Is this problem of my PC?

Comment: Can you provide xaml code?

Comment: Xelom, I have added the xaml code. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Change marging to Margin="10" and set Horizontal and VerticalAlignment to Stretch or Center.

Comment: voroninp, I have edited the source code but I get same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Problem here is Window Size includes the Chrome Size(Window Border and stuff like close/max min buttons).

Your Grid is hence the size you requested but it does not fit in the window size you've requested.

I could fix your issue to make the output window look like this, with Window size:

Width: 202
Height: 210

on Windows 8

However you should rather have your window size set to `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        x:Name="window"
        Title="MainWindow"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="171" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186">
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="151" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Your thus not assuming Chrome sizes which might be different from different versions of Windows.

You should also get [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It helps you debug such issues very easily, It shows a red border on a control when you hover on it with Shift+Ctrl, so you can actually see the `Grid` extend past the visible Window while showing the actual Element Layout of your UI

[image]