# Buttons are smaller while debugging wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I'm having a problem where, the second button in this code (has an image in it) looks around the same size as the first button, but when i debug the program, the button appears significantly smaller than it does in the preview. I'm stumped as to why it's happening. I'm using wpf, Visual Studio, and C#. Thanks for any help :)

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="160,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="31" Click="ClearButtonClick"/>
        <Button x:Name="ÇopyX" Margin="10,114,484,182" Click="CopyXClick">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source=" Resources/copySymbol.jpg"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Could be something with DpiAwareness.Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee308410(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WPF different size from IDE after debugging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710176/c-sharp-wpf-different-size-from-ide-after-debugging)

Comment: designer is not meant to be precise. And did you have designer size set to 200%?

Comment: `Margin="10,114,484,182"` indicates that you are *not* using xaml as you are supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that the height and width factors defaulted to auto. That meant they were scaling to the size of the window which was slightly smaller when i debugged. Setting the Height and Width to numbers kept them from scaling and setting the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Left and Top respectively kept them from moving.